# Popup is not loading in Entity Reference View Widget

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error "An error occurred while attempting to process /?q=system/ajax: params is undefined" while clicking attach button for Entity Reference View Widget. My jQuery version is 1.7.

Comment: This is due to the wysiwyg text editor. I tried with tinymce, ckeditor, niceeitor. But my Entity Reference View Widget is not loading if any one of editor is added to any fields in conten type. But without editor (Plain text editor for fields) Entity Reference View Widget popup is working.

Comment: Issue comes with jQuery 1.7. If its downgraded to version 1.5, all works.